# Best practice for moving changes across repositories

Tags: git

I have a code in github (commit A) which a colleague copied to gitlab (commit D). Let'say both are respective `main`. Then different commits go on top of them.

```
  = A --- B --- C     (Github main)
   
    = D --- E         (Gitlab main)
```

Here, `=` denotes that the history from Github are preserved in Gitlab.

Now I would like to have commit `C` in Gitlab and an easy way to achieve this is copying contents from `C` and making a commit `F` (I also moved `main` in gitlab to as a `temp` branch.

```
  = A --- B --- C     (Github main)
               \
   = D --- E --- F    (Gitlab main)
            \
            (Gitlab temp)
```

Rather than having just commit `F` is there a better way to do this (like preserving history from Github)?

Ideally I am looking for:

```
  = A --- B --- C     (Github main) // remains same

  = A --- B --- C     (Gitlab main)
   
    = D --- E         (Gitlab temp)
```

Comment: Are the histories of both repositories related/is there a common ancestor? Do you want commits A/B/C to be part of the GitLab repository as well?

Comment: Yes, `D` is preserved with histories prior to `A`. Yes, I would like commits `A`, `B`, `C` to be part of Gitlab as well.

Comment: `an easy way to achieve this is copying contents from C` There should be no copying involved, just add an additional remote rerence like [dan1st suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77159791/23118).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can create a local repository with two remotes, one representing the GitHub repository and one representing the GitLab repository.

```bash
# create a new repository and add the remotes
# it would also be possible in a similar way by cloning one and adding the other remote
git init
# make sure to change the username/reponame
# For self-hosted instances, you also need to change the domain names
git remote add github https://github.com/githubusername/reponame
git remote add gitlab https://gitlab.com/gitlabusername/reponame

# fetch content from remotes
git fetch --all
```

This way, you can use `git` commands for interacting with the repositories. Specifically, you can merge one into the other.

#### merging

You could create two branches (`github_main` and `gitlab_main`) from the `main` branches of both repositories:

```bash
git checkout -b github_main github/main
git checkout -b gitlab_main gitlab/main
```

Note that `github_main` is created before `gitlab_main` which means the branch `gitlab_main` is currently checked out (the currently checked out is the branch you are making changes to).

Then, you can just merge `github_main` into `gitlab_main`:

```bash
git merge github_main
```

This will create a new merge commit to your current branch (`gitlab_main`) with two ancestors: the `HEAD` commits of both branches.

At this point, you might want to inspect your changes, e.g. with `git log --all --graph`

After that, you can just push your changes to the `gitlab` remote.

```bash
git push -u gitlab gitlab_main:main
```

#### force-pushing one to the other

If you just want to change `main` on GitLab to be the same as the `main` branch on GitHub, just checkout the branch from GitLab and push it to GitHub. Since you are rewriting the history, you'd need to use a force-push:

```bash
git checkout -b github_main github/main
git push gitlab github_main:main --force-with-lease
```

Comment: Thanks. Would this also preserve `temp` branch without any issue? Like if `temp` branch tracks changes against `main` in gitlab and now that this changed? Could you please also update considering this info?

Comment: It does not change any branches except both `main` branches. If the branch exists before, it will stay as-is. If it doesn't, it won't be created. If you want to, you can create the branch. You can also check whether everything went alright before pushing using `git log --all --graph` (or similar, e.g. `git log --graph github_main gitlab_main`).

Comment: I fetched and got following error upon trying to create `github_main`: `fatal: 'refs/github/main' is not a commit and a branch 'github_main' cannot be created from it` . The `.git` folder contains `.git/refs/remotes/github/main`. So should I use `git checkout -b github_main refs/remotes/github/main` ?

Comment: Update: The above (in the last) command worked for me.

Comment: I do not want to merge but rather have `A-B-C` to gitlab. I do not want `C` to be merged with `E`. I think your above solution does merge? Is it?

Comment: Please see my update on question. I am looking for something like that.

Comment: So you want to essentially overwrite the GitLab branch with the GitHub branch?

Comment: Yes. I do not want commits D and E in the gitlab main (want to keep them in gitlab temp branch)

Comment: I added that to my answer. If you just force-push the main branch, other _existing_ branches shouldn't be effected.

Comment: The commits `D` and `E` (lets say I checkout a temp branch) and whatever branches were there in gitlab earlier would remain as it is even with the answer you mentioned?

Comment: I think you answered my above question. I assume *existing* branches in *gitlab* would remain unaffected.

Comment: The main branch on GitLab would be affected since that's what you want to change. Other branches shouldn't be affected.